# How to delete a single value from an array stored within a cookie

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a cookie

```
$.cookie("myvalue")
```

which contains an array of integer values. I just want to pass a value and check if the passed values matches with any of the values within the cookie then I want to remove that value from the cookie. I googled but could find something similar. Can anyone help out here.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddToCart").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");    
            if (typeof $.cookie('myvalue') == 'undefined') {
                $.cookie("myvalue", 0, { expiry: 1 });
            }
            var a = $(".img1").attr("id");
            var imgsrc = $.cookie("myvalue").split(",");
            var count = 0;
            var totalitems = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc.length; i++) {
                if (a == imgsrc[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            var lenghtOfArry = imgsrc.length;
            if (count >= lenghtOfArry) {
                $.cookie("myvalue",$.cookie("myvalue") + "," + a, { expiry: 10 });
            }
            else {
                alert('This value already exist');
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc.length; i++) {
                totalitems++;
            }
            $(".para").text("CART" + " " + "(" + totalitems + ")");
            $(".para").css("color", "#fff");
            $(".para").css("text-align", "center");
    });
});
```

Comment: First you should get array form cookie and then delete matched value from array and then reset this resulted cookie to your cookie

Comment: How does the array of integers kept in cookie ? Is there any delimeter ?

Comment: @ManojKumawat, Badhiya!!

Comment: Why not just save a JSON object/array in the cookie instead? That makes things much easier!

Comment: @ThiefMaster could you plz how to do that. Thanks

Comment: JSON.stringify(yourObject), save that in the cookie. to change it. JSON.parse(yourCookie), modify the returned object, and stringify it again and save it in the cookie.

Comment: @ThiefMaster can u plz explain the same with an example. Thanks